# How to create a search textbox with datagridview bound to BindingSource in C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindingsource

I wanna make a Search textbox on Data Grid View in C# and SQLServer, but datagridview bound to BindingSource.
i try this code Not function.

```
private void ucObat_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            db = new DbSIMP3Entities();
            tbObatBindingSource.DataSource = db.tbObats.ToList();
            tbSatuanBindingSource.DataSource = db.tbSatuans.ToList();
            tbKategoriBindingSource.DataSource = db.tbKategoris.ToList();
            tbMerkBindingSource.DataSource = db.tbMerks.ToList();

        }
private void txtSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tbObatBindingSource.Filter = "NmObat like '&" + txtSearch.Text + "&'";
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

[BindingSource.Filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter.aspx) will work only when your datasource implements `IBindingListView`

> Only underlying lists that implement the IBindingListView interface support filtering.

So, to make it work you've to change your underlying datasource.

If you don't wanna use `DataView` for some reason try using `BindingSource` itself as a datasource.

```
private BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
private BindingList<ObatsEntity> initialObats = new BindingList<ObatsEntity>();

private void ucObat_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    db = new DbSIMP3Entities();
    initialObats = new BindingList<ObatsEntity>( db.tbObats.ToList() );
    bs.DataSource = initialObats;
    dataGridView.DataSource = bs;
}

private void txtSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var filteredObats = new BindingList<ObatsEntity>( initialObats.Where( o => o.NmObat == txtSearch.Text ).ToList() );
    bs.DataSource = filteredObats;
    bs.ResetBindings();
}
```

Comment: If the filter or search is 'like txtSearch.Text'. what the code ?

Comment: That's the adequate operation: `initialObats.Where( o => o.NmObat == txtSearch.Text ).ToList()` - it will return only those items, which satisfy the condition `o.NmObat == txtSearch.Text ` - `==` is the [equality operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/equality-comparison-operator)